# 数式の改行と式番号について

Tags: latex

現在、次のように数式を含む文書をつくっています。

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    % 複数行の数式
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`equation->aligned`という構造は、複数行の数式をかたまりとして、式番号をひとつだけつけることを意図しています。しかし、この書き方では、ページをまたぐような行数のかたまりが、うまく改行せずにページをはみだしてしまいます。

`equation`,`aligned`環境以外をつかってもよいので、同じような式番号の付き方で、ページをまたぐときにうまく処理してくれるような書き方はありますか？

ためしたこと:

- `\allowdisplaybreaks`は`aligned`環境には効果がないようです
- `align`環境+`\notag`や、`align*`環境+`\tag`をもちいて手動で式番号を与えるのがもっとも近いですが、`equation+aligned`のように式番号が垂直中央寄せされませんでした

ドキュメントクラス・パッケージ・エンジンに依存するのであれば、これらを変更する方法でもかまいません

Comment: `aligned` 環境以外にも、 `split` や `gathered` 環境なども**内容を分割することの出来ないボックスとして扱う**ため、 
 `\displaybreak` コマンドや `\allowdisplaybreaks` コマンドが正常に動作しません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

少くとも標準的な方法では，お望みの出力を得る方法は存在しないかと思います．
なお，数式番号が付くディスプレイ数式は，その途中でページにより分割することは一般に許容されない事項です．